# How to resolve "error: cannot access com.intuit.karate.Results"

Tags: karate

I haven't seen this error before and no errors found in the script as well. I am clueless.

No issues when I execute it from Eclipse but when I execute it from the Command line prompt using the command - gradlew clean test, the error occurs.

Also imported the package - import com.intuit.karate.Results.

The complete Error message is provided below:

C:\Framework\karate-automation\src\test\java\featureFiles\AutomationRunner.java:7: error: cannot access com.intuit.karate.Results
import com.intuit.karate.Results;
^
bad class file: C:\Users\ch06.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.intuit.karate\karate-core\1.4.0\ede6f584a95cd2a987fc680f0479f91ca5567b14\karate-core-1.4.0.jar(com/intuit/karate/Results.class)
class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

Comment: sounds like your java versions don't match. refer linked q&a where someone got things working with eclipse + maven